# I am trying to UPDATE a last 10 films watched column in my python code for a basic movie service using sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

In the section of my code where it checks the last digit of the filmswatched variable, I am trying to use the last digit to determine what last film column to place the film name into. However, nothing is being updated into my database. I would greatly appreciate any help with identifying the mistake in my code. Also, you can ignore most of the commented code as its just my failed, but not forgotten, attempts at making a GUI for the service.

```
#importing sqlite so that a database can be made.
import sqlite3
#importing tkinter to enable GUI use.
import tkinter
#importing to time to add sleeps for aesthetics/
from time import sleep
#importing re for password check
import re

##Using sqlite to create a database that holds a table for UserInfo
with sqlite3.connect("accounts.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserInfo(
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
        password text NOT NULL,
        fullname text NOT NULL,
        streetname text NOT NULL,
        city text NOT NULL,
        postcode text NOT NULL,
        dob text NOT NULL,
        gender text NOT NULL,
        favouritegenre text NOT NULL,
        filmswatched int NOT NULL,
        film1 text NOT NULL,
        film2 text NOT NULL,
        film3 text NOT NULL,
        film4 text NOT NULL,
        film5 text NOT NULL,
        film6 text NOT NULL,
        film7 text NOT NULL,
        film8 text NOT NULL,
        film9 text NOT NULL,
        film10 text NOT NULL);""")
    actionArray = ["1.Die Hard","2.The Matrix","3.The Dark Knight","4.Mad Max","5.Taken","6.Wonder Woman","7.Baby Driver","8.John Wick","9.Logan","10.Thor: Ragnarok"]
    scifiArray = ["1.Star Wars","2.Star Wars: The Last Jedi","3.E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial","4.Interstellar","5.Star Trek","6.Alien","7.District 9","8.Ex Machina","9.Avatar","WALL-E"]
    horrorArray = ["1.It","2.Saw","3.Get Out","4.The Shining","5.Nightmare on Elm Street","6.It Follows","7.Halloween","8.The Babadook","9.The Descent","10.The Blair With Project"]
    db.commit()

#Making a main menu.
def startup_menu():
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.configure(bg="light blue")
    window.geometry("200x300")
    signupButton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Sign Up", bg="#4798d1", command=lambda: createUser())
    loginButton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", bg="#4798d1", command=lambda: login())
    signupButton.pack()
    loginButton.pack()
    window.mainloop()



#Creating a function for creating a new user to be implemented in a startup menu.
def createUser():
    with sqlite3.connect("accounts.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        newUsername = input("What is your username: ")
        newPasswordStatus = False
        while newPasswordStatus != True:
            newPassword = input("What is your password (it must have a capital letter and a number): ")
            if any(c.isupper() for c in newPassword) == True and any(c.isdigit() for c in newPassword) == True:
                newPasswordStatus = True
        newName = input("What is your full name: ")
        newStreetname = input("What is your streetname: ")
        newCity = input("What is your city: ")
        newPostcode = input("What is your postcode: ")
        newDoB = input("What is your date of birt: ")
        newGender = input("What is your gender: ")
        newFavouriteGenre = input("What is your favorite genre out of Action, Sci-Fi and Horror: ")
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO UserInfo(username, password, fullname, streetname, city, postcode, dob, gender, favouritegenre, filmswatched, film1, film2, film3, film4, film5, film6, film7, film8, film9, film10)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,0,"N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A")""",
                       (newUsername, newPassword, newName, newStreetname, newCity, newPostcode, newDoB, newGender, newFavouriteGenre))
        db.commit()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE username=? AND password=?",(newUsername,newPassword))
        print(cursor.fetchall())
        print("")
        startChoice = input("Would you like to:\n 1.Go to the startup menu.\n 2.Create a new user.\n 3.Login as a user.")
        if startChoice == "1":
            startup_menu()
        elif startChoice == "2":
            createUser()
        elif startChoice == "3":
            login()



def login():
    with sqlite3.connect("accounts.db") as db:
        global enterUsername
        enterUsername = input("Username:")
        global enterPassword
        enterPassword = input("Password:")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE username=? and password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
        passwordGood = cursor.fetchone()
    if passwordGood:
        print("Password is good!")
        print("")
        moviebox()
    else:
        print("Your password or username was incorrect. Please try again.")
        login()

def moviebox():
    with sqlite3.connect("accounts.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
    print("Welcome to the MovieBox service!")
    print("")
    print("We have a wide choice of movies to offer you. Pick from our three available genres: Action, Sci-Fi and Horror.")
    choiceMade = False
    while choiceMade != True:
        genreChoice = input("What genre do you want to watch?")
        genreChoice = genreChoice.lower()
        if genreChoice == "action":
            choiceMade = True
            print("")
            print("Your choices of movie are: \n",actionArray)
            movieChoice1 = int(input("What number movie do you want to watch?"))
            i = movieChoice1
            global movieName
            movieName = actionArray[i-1]
            movieName = movieName[2:]
            print("Thank you for watching ",movieName)
            cursor.execute("UPDATE UserInfo SET filmswatched = filmswatched+1 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
            db.commit()
            cursor.execute("SELECT filmswatched FROM UserInfo WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
            filmswatched = cursor.fetchall()
            int(filmswatched)
            print(filmswatched)
            if filmswatched[-1]==("0"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film10 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("1"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film1 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("2"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film2 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("3"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film3 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("4"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film4 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("5"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film5 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("6"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film6 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("7"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film7 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("8"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film8 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            elif filmswatched[-1]==("9"):
                cursor.execute("""UPDATE film9 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword)""", VALUES(movieName,))
                db.commit()
            cursor.execute("SELECT film10 FROM UserInfo WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            print(result)
            sleep(1)
            moviebox()
        elif genreChoice == "sci-fi":
            choiceMade = True
            print("")
            print("Your choices of movie are: \n",scifiArray)
            movieChoice1 = int(input("What number movie do you want to watch?"))
            i = movieChoice1
            movieName = scifiArray[i-1]
            movieName = movieName[2:]
            print("Thank you for watching ",movieName)
            cursor.execute("UPDATE UserInfo SET filmswatched = filmswatched+1 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
            db.commit()
            cursor.execute("SELECT filmswatched FROM UserInfo WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
            filmswatched = cursor.fetchall()
        elif genreChoice == "horror":
            choiceMade = True
            print("")
            print("Your choices of movie are: \n",horrorArray)
            movieChoice1 = int(input("What number movie do you want to watch?"))
            i = movieChoice1
            movieName = horrorArray[i-1]
            movieName = movieName[2:]
            print("Thank you for watching ",movieName)
            cursor.execute("UPDATE UserInfo SET filmswatched = filmswatched+1 WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
            db.commit()
            cursor.execute("SELECT filmswatched FROM UserInfo WHERE username=? AND password=?",(enterUsername, enterPassword))
            filmswatched = cursor.fetchall()
        db.commit()









#Creating a function for creating a new user through a GUI.
##def create_User():
##    with sqlite3.connect("accounts.db") as db:
##        cursor = db.cursor()
##    global signup_window
##    signup_window = tkinter.Tk()
##    signup_window.configure(bg="light blue")
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="Here you will create your user.", bg="light blue").pack()
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your username:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newUsernameEntry
##    newUsernameEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newUsernameEntry.pack()
##    global newUsername
##    newUsername = newUsernameEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your password (it must have a capital letter and a number):", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newPasswordEntry
##    newPasswordEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newPasswordEntry.pack()
##    global newPassword
##    newPassword = newPasswordEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your full name:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newNameEntry
##    newNameEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newNameEntry.pack()
##    global newName
##    newName = newNameEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your streetname:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newStreetnameEntry
##    newStreetnameEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newStreetnameEntry.pack()
##    global newStreetname
##    newStreetname = newStreetnameEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your city:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newCityEntry
##    newCityEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newCityEntry.pack()
##    global newCity
##    newCity = newCityEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your postcode:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newPostcodeEntry
##    newPostcodeEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newPostcodeEntry.pack()
##    global newPostcode
##    newPostcode = newPostcodeEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your date of birth:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newDoBEntry
##    newDoBEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newDoBEntry.pack()
##    global newDoB
##    newDoB = newDoBEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your gender:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newGenderEntry
##    newGenderEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newGenderEntry.pack()
##    global newGender
##    newGender = newGenderEntry.get()
##    
##    
##    tkinter.Label(signup_window, text="What is your favorite genre out of Action, Sci-Fi and Horror:", bg="light blue").pack()
##    global newFavouriteGenreEntry
##    newFavouriteGenreEntry = tkinter.Entry(signup_window)
##    newFavouriteGenreEntry.pack()
##    global newFavouriteGenre
##    newFavouriteGenre = newFavouriteGenreEntry.get()
##    db.commit()
##    
##
##    tkinter.Button(signup_window, text="Sign Up", bg="#4798d1", command= lambda: signup_check_password()).pack()


##def signup_check_password():
##    global newPasswordStatus
##    newPasswordStatus = False
##    while newPasswordStatus != True:
##        if any(c.isupper() for c in newPasswordEntry.get()) == True and any(c.isdigit() for c in newPasswordEntry.get()) == True:
##            newPasswordStatus = True
##            newUsername = newUsernameEntry.get()
##            newPassword = newPasswordEntry.get()
##            newName = newNameEntry.get()
##            newStreetname = newStreetnameEntry.get()
##            newCity = newCityEntry.get()
##            newPostcode = newPostcodeEntry.get()
##            newDoB = newDoBEntry.get()
##            newGender = newGenderEntry.get()
##            newFavouriteGenre = newFavouriteGenreEntry.get()
##            with sqlite3.connect("accounts.db") as db:
##                cursor = db.cursor()
##            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO UserInfo(username, password, fullname, streetname, city, postcode, dob, gender, favouritegenre)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
##                   (newUsername, newPassword, newName, newStreetname, newCity, newPostcode, newDoB, newGender, newFavouriteGenre))
##            db.commit()
##
##            signup_window.quit()
##        else:
##            signup_window.destroy()
##            retryWindow = tkinter.Tk()
##            retryWindow.configure(bg="light blue")
##            tkinter.Label(retryWindow, text="Your password did not meet the requirements. Try again.").pack()
##            tkinter.Button(retryWindow, text="OK", command= lambda: create_User())
##def signup_check_password():
##    global newPasswordStatus
##    newPasswordStatus = False
##    while newPasswordStatus != True:
##        if password_check(newPassword) == True:
##            newPasswordStatus = True
##            insert_userinfo()
##            signup_window.quit()
##        else:
##            retryWindow = tkinter.Tk()
##            retryWindow.configure(bg="light blue")
##            tkinter.Label(retryWindow, text="Your password did not meet the requirements. Try again.", bg="light blue").pack()
##            tkinter.Button(retryWindow, text="OK", command= lambda: create_User())
##    

def password_check(password):
    if any(c.isupper() for c in newPassword) == True and any(c.isdigit() for c in newPassword) == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False



##def insert_userinfo():
##    with sqlite3.connect("accounts.db") as db:
##        cursor = db.cursor()
##    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO UserInfo(username, password, fullname, streetname, city, postcode, dob, gender, favouritegenre)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""",
##            (newUsername, newPassword, newName, newStreetname, newCity, newPostcode, newDoB, newGender, newFavouriteGenre))
##    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserInfo")
##    for x in cursor.fetchall():
##        print(x)




startup_menu()

db.commit()
```

Comment: I would say that you need to completely restructure your database. It's a violation of first normal form (the absolute bare minimum of good database structure) to have a list of columns (`film1, film2, film3, etc.`) like you've got. I do not think it is worth your effort to try to fix this. Reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Designs_that_Violate_1NF) and then going back to reevaluate your structure will be a better use of your time. The difficulties you're having will clear up pretty quickly if you fix this.

Comment: If I were to make changes based on first normal form, how would I shift the different movie names along when the user watches another movie. The service only needs to retain the last 10  films watched as I intend to make a recommendation algorithm too.